# meteor + velocity + jasmine-unit stuck at loading

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, velocity

I would like know why this jasmine-unit test gets stuck at "loading".

This is my test and addUser calls a Accounts.createUser() method on the server side which normally returns an id of added user when done:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var InsertUser = function()
    {
        var id;

        id = Meteor.methodMap.addUser('asd@asd.asd', 'asdasd', 'John', 'Doe', 'not yet', '070-111 22 33', 'ididididid', 'admin', 'info admin john', 0);

        console.log("1. call method: " + id);

        this.getIdOfUser = function()
        {
            return id;
        };
    };

    describe("User functions", function ()
    {
        var userInsert;

        beforeEach(function(done)
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                userInsert = new InsertUser();
                console.log("2. before each");
                done();
            }, 1000);
        });

        it("Add user return value", function(done)
        {
            spyOn(userInsert, 'getIdOfUser');

            console.log("3. use spy");

            expect(userInsert.getIdOfUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
})();
```

I am here trying to use the asynchronus way of calling addUser to get the id returned by the method on the server side.

Adding a user works if I manually call the "addUser" method from the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the app with `DEBUG=1 JASMINE_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1 mrt` so you can see if any error is thrown during the tests execution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I was told, you have to also open the mirror app at `http://localhost:5000`. Did it help? Also check in console that mirror app is correctly opening.